# Find the surface area of the patch of the graph $z = -x^5-y^2+e^{xy-1}$ for $1\leqq x \leqq 1.1$ and $1\leqq y \leqq 1.2$

Tags: linear-algebra, surface-integrals

I am struggling with this:

> Find the surface area of the patch of the graph $z = -x^5-y^2+e^{xy-1}$ for $1\leqq x \leqq 1.1$ and $1\leqq y \leqq 1.2$

I am unsure of how to go about solving this.

I have already tried solving it by parametrizing the equation in terms of $r$ and $\theta$, then taking double integral of the cross products of $F_r$ and $F_\theta$. However, I am unsure of how to find the bounds of $r$ after.

> I'm looking for an approximate result.

Also, I tried solving while keeping it in $xy$ coordinates, however I get a problem when solving for $dS$. The $dS$ I get seems a bit too complicated than what seems to be intended, and I feel i'm missing an important step somewhere. I'm guessing perhaps this has to do with whether I'm looking for an approximate or exact result.

Comment: It seems like polar coordinates would only lead to heartache. Your patch is already a rectangle in $xy$ coordinates, so moving to polar would only make it look worse. Try staying in $xy$ first.

Comment: are you looking for an exact or approximate result ?

Comment: I'm looking for an approximate result. Also, I tried solving while keeping it in xy coordinates, however I get a problem when solving for dS. The dS I get seems a bit too complicated than what seems to be intended and I feel i'm missing an important step somewhere. I'm guessing perhaps this has to do with whether I'm looking for an approximate or exact result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the size of the patch, a 0.1 by 0.2 rectangle, is rather small, an analytic approximate for the surface integral over this small space can be derived

Give that the upper limits $x=1.1$ and $y=1.2$ are both close to 1, the function $z$ can be expanded around $x=y=1$. To the first order in $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1$, $z$ can be approximated as,

$$z(u,v) = -(1+u)^5-(1+v )^2 +e^{(1+u)(1+v)-1}\approx -1 - 4u-v$$

Then, $z_u’= -4$ and $z_v’= -1$, and the surface integral is,

$$S= \int_0^{0.2}\int_0^{0.1} \sqrt{1+(z_u’)^2+(z_v’)^2}dudv$$
$$=\int_0^{0.2}\int_0^{0.1}\sqrt{18}dudv=0.06\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Everything seems understandable to me except the approximation of _z(u,v)_ . How did you reach that approximation?

Comment: @zehFlowr - I applied the first-order Taylor expansion to each of the 3 terms in $z$. For example, for $f(u)=-(1+u)^5 \approx f(1)+f(1)’u=-1-5u$. So, if you add the 3 expansions, you get $z=-1-4u-v$